# js destructure and define field

Tags: javascript, destructuring

if I have the following object:

```
const obj = { 
  a: {
    b: 'val',
  },
};
```

and I want to destructure both `a` and `b` from the object, how would I go about doing it? I know this:

```
const { a: { b } } = obj;
```

but this doesn't let me access `a`. How can I also make `a` accessible in the code?

Answer (score 1):

Just include it.

```js
const obj = { 
  a: {
    b: 'val',
  },
};

const { a, a: { b } } = obj;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```